Error: Could not find or load main class simulator.launcher.Main Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: simulator.launcher.Main
I have created a project in Eclipse, and I want to run it using cmd, so I have copied the .bin folder to my desktop and from that address I am trying to run it, my project uses libraries, specifically the ones I put in the screenshot, but I can't get it to run via CMD (Try "java -classpath tp.jar:/lib/.jar:lib/json.jar:tp.jar:/lib/.jar:lib/commons-cli-1.4. jar: simulator.launcher.Main"), but I always get the same error, could someone help me? I have attached the paths where the important files are located. Thank you.Main.classlibraries
I have tried variations of the code above but it has not worked, I am trying to run my project using CMD, but I have no idea how to do it.

Those paths are Unix paths. Even on a Unix setup they wouldn't be quite right, but you're using Windows. The path separator is ; not : Something more like java -classpath tp.jar;lib\something-missing-here.jar;lib\json.jar;lib\commons-cli-1.4.jar simulator.launcher.Main

Look into tools that can build a fat jar with all your dependencies includes, like Maven or Gradle and a fatjar plugin.

Thank you very much, i looked on the proyect configuration on eclpise, and i found the problem was that when i executed the command, couldnt find the libraries i used on my proyect.
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-classpath "bin;lib\commons-cli-1.4.jar;lib\json.jar;plugins\org.junit.jupiter.api_5.8.1.v20211018-1956.jar;plugins\org.junit.jupiter.engine_5.8.1.v20211018-1956.jar;plugins\org.junit.jupiter.migrationsupport_5.8.1.v20211018-1956.jar;plugins\org.junit.jupiter.params_5.8.1.v20211018-1956.jar;plugins\org.junit.platform.commons_1.8.1.v20211018-1956.jar;plugins\org.junit.platform.engine_1.8.1.v20211018-1956.jar;plugins\org.junit.platform.launcher_1.8.1.v20211018-1956.jar;plugins\org.junit.platform.runner_1.8.1.v20211018-1956.jar;plugins\org.junit.platform.suite.api_1.8.1.v20211018-1956.jar;plugins\org.junit.platform.suite.engine_1.8.1.v20211028-1957.jar;plugins\org.junit.platform.suite.commons_1.8.1.v20211018-1956.jar;plugins\org.junit.vintage.engine_5.8.1.v20211018-1956.jar;plugins\org.opentest4j_1.2.0.v20211018-1956.jar;plugins\org.apiguardian_1.1.2.v20211018-1956.jar;plugins\org.junit_4.13.2.v20211018-1956.jar;plugins\org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v20180420-1519.jar"
-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages simulator.launcher.Main
So i moved a copy of all libraries i used, to a folder called plugins that was in the folder i created on my desktop with the proyect, and executing the code above, form cmd i was able to run my royect finally. Thanks very much for your help.

That's good. Of course, a lot of that is for testing only, so you won't need that huge classpath for running it under normal circumstances
